# !: (bang colon) notation in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I found `!:` notation being used in [Angular Deprecation docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#dependency-on-a-reflect-metadata-polyfill-in-jit-mode).

```
@Input() tpl !: TemplateRef<any>;
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) inlineTemplate !: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Found the same [here as well](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#usage-notes).

```
@Input() id !: string;
```

I'm not sure what is the terminology (or concept behind) for `!:` notation in Angular. Googling didn't help me much. Tried [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%21%3A+angular) and Angular Docs for the same, but all in vain.

It'd be helpful if someone could shed some light on it, like how does it function, or share the doc link at the very least.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you have `strictNullChecks` on then anything you decorate with `@Input` will usually complain.  For example...

```
public class MyComponent {

  @Input()
  public myField: string;

  constructor() {}

}
```

This will lead to TS complaining.  This is because `myField` has not be declared nullable so it should never be set to `null` or `undefined`.  At the same time, it is not initialized in the constructor, so it will get an initial value of `undefined`.

Normally, this is fine.  We know that Angular will set the value shortly after construction.  If we mark the field nullable `public myField: string?` then we will have to deal with `this field may be null` errors all over the place when we try and use it.

So, as a compromise, we throw a `!` on the field declaration to tell Typescript "I know this looks like it is getting initialized to null/undefined but trust me, I will take care of it".

Comment: Gotcha! Glad you answered with the explanation. Would be helpful for future readers

Answer (score 16):

The exclamation mark `!` tells, that the field is *non-null non-undefined* (see [Microsoft's TypeScript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)).

The colon `:` is just the separator between field name and type.

Comment: oh so its more of a feature of Typescript not related to Angular in general

Comment: I've used `something!.property` several times, but never `something !: string`. Now the question itself feels silly. anyways thanks for the prompt reply. Upvotes for you, but accepted tick goes to Pace for the explanation :)