# Typescript variables with ? and?

Tags: typescript

When I declare a variable in typescript like below:

`id: number`

I get the following error:

`Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`

If I change the variable to one of the following, the error goes away:

- `id?: number`
- `id!: number`

What are the differences between those and what situations I should use the  above?

Comment: `id?` means that the variable can be `null` or `undefined` and `id!` means it will be initialized, but not in the constructor. This should be explained in the Typescript documentation

Comment: @UnholySheep `id?` does not include `null` in the domain

Comment: And you can't use `?` with locals ("variables"), only properties and parameters.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, right my bad - I mistakenly thought it includes the same types as the non-null assertion operator

Comment: One of you can post the answer instead of a comment. I will mark that as answer.

Comment: @wonderfulworld I sincerely doubt this is not a duplicate.

Comment: [What does !: mean in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50983838) | [!: (bang colon) notation in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58073841) | [Exclamation Mark in type definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57816914) | [What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37632760)

Comment: I don't think my question is duplicate. The ? discussed in that question was in the context of angular Javascript framework.

Comment: @wonderfulworld why do you think Angular uses any other language than TypeScript? Angular is simply a framework. It doesn't change how language features work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write this:

```
class Optional {
  id?: number;
}
```

you have declared that `id` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties). That means it may or may not be present in an instance of `Optional`.  If it is present, the value should be a `number` (or possibly `undefined` unless you are using [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)).  If it is not present, then if you read the `id` property, the value will be `undefined`.

The above resolves the compiler warning because you are not required to initialize a property that's optional; it will just be `undefined` when you read it.

Anyway that means you cannot just use the `id` property as a `number`:

```
const o = new Optional();
o.id.toFixed(2) // compiler error!
//~~ <-- Object is possibly undefined
```

That warning is good, right?  Because you don't want to accidentally read the `toFixed()` method of `undefined`.  You need to *check* for `undefined` first, possibly by using the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```
o.id?.toFixed(2) // okay
```

Optional properties are a reasonable approach when you are not sure if the properties will be assigned by the time users want to access them, and you want to protect these users from potential runtime errors.

---

On the other hand, when you write this:

```
class Asserted {
  id!: number
}
```

you have *asserted* that the `id` property [has definitely been assigned](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions). That assertion is you telling the compiler something it can't verify for itself.  This is useful in situations where you actually do assign the property but the compiler cannot follow the logic:

```
class ActuallyAssigned {
  id!: number
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { id: 123 });
  }
}
```

An instance of `ActuallyAssigned` will have the `id` property set in the constructor, because [the `Object.assign()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies properties into the first parameter from all subsequent parameters.  But the compiler cannot understand this, and so without the definite assignment assertion, you'd get a warning.  Silencing that warning is reasonable here.

But in `Asserted` above, it's not reasonable.  You have lied to the compiler.  It can't see that `id` has be assigned because it actually has *not* been assigned.  And so you will not get a compiler warning if you go ahead and treat the `id` property like a `number`, even though it might be `undefined`:

```
a.id.toFixed(2) // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR: o.id is undefined
```

Definite assignment assertions are therefore not recommended for situations when properties will quite possibly be `undefined` when users want to access them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYBNoG8CwAoa0CWCBc0AdgK4C2ARgKYBOGAvhhqJDAPIAOALtgPaFggUGLLgD8BEhRoBueo3TA+ETtB7QAvEUoB3aB258BACgCUs9J2oBPIZlUA6XPc48AYtgAelBEYBMJ6AB6QOgaah5qAEJhIMCAPzjoAB4AWhS9cgArSmAVbBh2HihschAbYkIESgAzbEJvemhgME5gAAtoI0oA5CalHhBKexAeAHMugLpYh1wcGAqq2vqkFuhqCu5SSnkeRwRRZzdPbz8A4NUAazAreSZwKGgAQSgaTm9bEQRIiTIqWnQGAolCowBotLpnhBXiczBhLDY0HYwHtDu4vD5-NNCGpFKR2NhBtRQtRwv8ps1Wh0Jig+oQIAMhiNxt1oFNzrtZvloAsanV3qt1oRNtt0LdRQp7jBHrliAIypDsKNlh8cF8flJ-lhFHTLMRchFTCqsKwsjlOPYWIrCEZOG18gAaGm4AgARl8AGZWbC7IDARggA)